# How to get-date automatically in AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I want to automate a task to download my azure ad audit logs on daily basis. Can i use the Get-date in the below command instead of entering the mannual data.

Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDateTime gt 2019-03-20" | Export-Csv c:\auditlogs.csv

Comment: Hi @Parveen kumar do you mean including `Get-date` output in filter of  `Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs `?

Comment: Yes, because i don't want to put the data manually every day. I want to automate this process with the task scheduler. so I need the Get-Data parameter in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got results successfully.**

Please check the below code which I tried,
Here I used **`get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"`** to get the correct format of the get-date.

**Code:**

```
$date = get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDateTime gt $date" | Export-Csv -Path "< Path to store >"
```

**Console:**

[image]

**File:**

After command runned successfully you can view the csv file which is stored in your local path.

[image]

**Reference:**
[Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs (AzureADPreview) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadauditdirectorylogs?view=azureadps-2.0-preview)

Comment: Yes, now the codes are working fine. can I set the csv file name as data like "20221123" automatically

Comment: Yeah you can save the file name as 20221123.csv

Comment: I can give the name manually, that I know. my question is can I automate the file name? because I don't want to give the name every day. can the script generate the file name by date

Comment: Thanks for your help. i have achieved the requirement by modifying the script

$date = get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$filename = get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDateTime gt $date" | Export-Csv -Path c:\$filename.csv